# How to get distance between two locations in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, .net-4.5

In Windows Phone 8 there seems to be method

```
   GeoCoordinate.GetDistanceTo()
```

for calculating distances between two locations. (Even if [the reference page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinate.getdistanceto(v=vs.110).aspx) for the method is not found.)

But where is the equivalent in the whole [Windows Phone 8.1 Geolocation namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.geolocation.aspx)?

I can't find a method to calculate distance between two locations at all.

How to calculate distance between two locations in WP8.1?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`GeoCoordinate.GetDistanceTo()` is found in `System.Device.Location` namespace. But windows 8.1 (Runtime apps) apps use `Windows.Devices.Geolocation` namespace where `GetDistanceTo()` method is not present.

So you can calculate the distance yourself by using the **Haversine formula**. Here is the [wikipedia Haversine page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula), you can know about the formula from there.

You can use the below C# code which uses Haversine formula to calculate the distance between two coordinates.

```
using System;  
namespace HaversineFormula  
{  
/// <summary>  
/// The distance type to return the results in.  
/// </summary>  
public enum DistanceType { Miles, Kilometers };  
/// <summary>  
/// Specifies a Latitude / Longitude point.  
/// </summary>  
public struct Position  
{  
    public double Latitude;  
    public double Longitude;  
}  
class Haversine  
{  
    /// <summary>  
    /// Returns the distance in miles or kilometers of any two  
    /// latitude / longitude points.  
    /// </summary>  
    public double Distance(Position pos1, Position pos2, DistanceType type)  
    {  
        double R = (type == DistanceType.Miles) ? 3960 : 6371;  
        double dLat = this.toRadian(pos2.Latitude - pos1.Latitude);  
        double dLon = this.toRadian(pos2.Longitude - pos1.Longitude);  
        double a = Math.Sin(dLat / 2) * Math.Sin(dLat / 2) +  
            Math.Cos(this.toRadian(pos1.Latitude)) * Math.Cos(this.toRadian(pos2.Latitude)) *  
            Math.Sin(dLon / 2) * Math.Sin(dLon / 2);  
        double c = 2 * Math.Asin(Math.Min(1, Math.Sqrt(a)));  
        double d = R * c;  
        return d;  
    }  
    /// <summary>  
    /// Convert to Radians.  
    /// </summary>  
    private double toRadian(double val)  
    {  
        return (Math.PI / 180) * val;  
    }  
}
```